# How to add multiple entry points for React in Laravel project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rc-slider

Is there a possibility to set singe value on React rc-slider Range component? At present to do that I need to drag the second handle in front of the first one  or the first one drag after the second one and this behavior is allowing user to drag the handle behind the rail if we are on the edge values [image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to set this up like on the third image it would show from eg. 39 to 39. Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Slider, { Range } from "rc-slider";
import "rc-slider/assets/index.css";

export const RangeSlider = ({
    min,
    max,
    error,
    displayUnit,
    stereo,
    onChange
}) => {
    const [minVal, setMinVal] = useState(min);
    const [maxVal, setMaxVal] = useState(max);
    const props = {
        onChange: value => {
            if (stereo) {
                setMinVal(value[0]);
                setMaxVal(value[1]);
            } else {
                setMinVal(value);
                setMaxVal(value);
            }
            onChange(value);
        },
        min: min,
        max: max,
        defaultValue: stereo ? [0, 100] : 0
    };
    return (
        <>
            {error && (
                <span className="position-outside">
                    <i className="fas fa-exclamation-circle fa text-danger mt-2"></i>
                </span>
            )}
            <div className="text-primary h6 mb-3">
                <strong>
                    {stereo &&
                        `Od ${minVal}${
                            displayUnit ? " " + displayUnit : ""
                        } do ${maxVal}${displayUnit ? " " + displayUnit : ""}`}
                    {!stereo &&
                        `${minVal}${displayUnit ? " " + displayUnit : ""}`}
                </strong>
            </div>
            {stereo ? <Range {...props} /> : <Slider {...props} />}
        </>
    );
};
```

I am aware that single range slider is for single values, although the client has requested this feature.
Thanks

Comment: If you just need a single value for your slider it is very likely you don't need that external package. Just use a browser native slider like: ```<input type="range" id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="11">```

Comment: I have a few of them in the project, it is a client's requirement to make it work the way I described above, but thanks :)

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve. If you could explain your requirements better that would help

Comment: I have just noticed i totally mismatched the title with the content I am sory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly my apologies for making a confusion with the title and a question, the title should be different, I have found the bug I thought it was rc-slider, however it was me translating the second rail to be contained within the track, I have explained everything in detail in this post [styling rc-slider track to contain handles within itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69141901/styling-rc-slider-track-to-contain-handles-within-itself) therefore I am closing this one. Thanks