# styling rc-slider track to contain handles within itself

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, rc-slider

By default, the handles in React rc-slider are translated by -50% and their style is that the handle overlaps the rail,
[image]
but I need the handles to be contained within the rail, after expanding the rail and shrinking the handles the style presents as below
[image]
as you can see, the handles are outside the track and I need them to be contained within, I have tried to translate them by zero or by 0 for the left one and 100% for the right one, but this would cause them to overlap one another like so[image] if not that they overlap, this would be the behavior I am after [image]
here are my styles

```
.rc-slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    touch-action: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.rc-slider * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.rc-slider-rail {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f9f8f8;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;

}
.rc-slider-track {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #CDEA9F;
    opacity: 70%;
}
.rc-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: grab;
    border-radius: 40%;
    background-color: #8ECC29;
    touch-action: pan-x;
}

.rc-slider-handle-1 {
    transform: translateX(0) !important; <- this is wrong as can overlap

}
.rc-slider-handle-2 {
    transform: translateX(-100%) !important;<- this is wrong as can overlap

}
```

because the width is set dynamically I can not scale it or anything. I ran out of ideas so please help :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"but this would cause them to overlap one another like so"* - what else should happen if the range is 0 width?

Comment: so what solution would you suggest @TJ ?